# issue with communicating between two different c programs using pipes

Tags: c, linux, terminal, pipe, fork

Iv'e been asked the following task:

> I need to create two C programs, **ex1.c** and **ex2.c**. **ex1** needs to fork and execute **ex2**. In addition, **ex1** needs to send 2 strings and 1 integer into **ex2** using a pipe. Moreover, **ex2** have to send an integer number to **ex1** also using a pipe.

This is the code I was able to type until now:

(Now updated)

**ex1.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    int pipefd[2];
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int integerData = 42;
    char string1[] = "Hello good";
    char string2[] = "World ";

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // Child process (loopcmp.c)
        close(pipefd[1]);  // Close the write end of the pipe

        // Redirect stdin to read from the pipe
        if (dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
            perror("dup2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Execute ex1.c
        execlp("./ex1", "ex1", NULL);

        // If execlp returns, an error occurred
        perror("execlp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        // Parent process (nicecmp.c)
        close(pipefd[0]);  // Close the read end of the pipe

        // Serialize the data as a single string
        char buffer[256];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s:%s:%d", string1, string2, integerData);

        // Write the serialized string to the pipe
        if (write(pipefd[1], buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1) {
            perror("write");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        close(pipefd[1]);  // Close the write end of the pipe

        // Wait for the child process to finish
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        int num;
        read(pipefd[0], &num, sizeof(int));
        close(pipefd[0]);
        printf("the num from loopcmp: %d\n",num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**ex2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[256];
    // Read the serialized string from stdin (the pipe)
    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) == -1) {
        perror("read");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Parse the data from the serialized string
    char string1[100];
    char string2[100];
    int integerData;
    sscanf(buffer, "%[^:]:%[^:]:%d", string1, string2, &integerData);

    // Now you have the two strings and the integer data from nicecmp.c
    
    printf("Received data from nicecmp.c:\n");
    printf("String 1: %s\n", string1);
    printf("String 2: %s\n", string2);
    printf("Integer: %d\n", integerData);
    int num = 556;
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &num, sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling both programs, and running `./ex1` I get the following message (don't relate to name of files it's the same code)[image: output]

I'm trying to read the number from **ex2** back into **ex1**, but it shows that the number that is read is `0`, how can I Solve it?

Comment: Did you learn about `dup2`?

Comment: You *can* pass read end of pipe as STDIN to child process (using `dup2()`) but in general you don't have to. For example, you can pass read end descriptor as command line parameter.

Comment: @dimich If I use the STDIN_FILENO, so I Can get from it the values onto ex2, how do i insert the 2 strings and integer into the ex1_to_ex2 pipe? is it possible by doing 
write(ex1_to_ex2[1],str1,sizeof(str1)) etc? in the parent process

Comment: @TomJames You have to design a sort of communication protocol. If order of data is known and fixed, you can send integers "as is": `write(ex1_to_ex2[1], &num, sizeof(num))`. For string you have to know where it ends. So you should either send string length as integer first, or send string with null terminator. Former is simpler to implement. Keep in mind, `read()` from pipe may return less bytes than requested.

Comment: @dimich Iv'e got a few changes to the code, was able to get the values from ex1 to ex2, but couldnt get the num from ex2 to ex1, I tried to write the num from ex2 into the STDOUT_FILENO, and then read it from the pipefd[0] because pipefd[1] is connected to the STDIN_FILENO

Comment: @TomJames In new version child's STDIN_FILENO is redirected to read end of the pipe but STDOUT_FILENO left unchanged. You should redirect it to write end of another pipe. Your first intent with two pipes `ex1_to_ex2[]` and `ex2_to_ex1[]` was correct. Pipes are unidirectional, so you need two pipes for bidirectional communication.